# Dask Add New Column Based on the Previous Column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dask, large-data

I'm using Dask library to analyze my data.

I have this set of data and I would like to add new column which is  Phone No. Flag:

```
ID   Phone No
001   NaN
002   O123421
003   Nan
```

My wish output is like this, where if the user have NaN on phone No flag as '0' else '1':

```
ID    Phone No   Phone No Flag
001    NaN           0
002    O123421       1
003    Nan           0
```

Anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dask support the regular `pandas` syntax, so the code below is same as one would do it in `pandas`:

```py
ddf['phone_no_flag'] = ddf['phone_no'].isna() * 1
```

Multiplication by 1 is to get 0/1 values rather than True/False.

Comment: Can you please add some explanations to your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples. You can make use of `np.where` and `.isnull()` functions here. Simply checking condition by np.where if column(Phone No)'s value is NaN then assign 0 to new column OR assign 1 to new column value.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1['Phone No Flag']=np.where(df1['Phone No'].isnull(),0,1)
```